# please wait a momnet Loader in javascript, css,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

i have a little Javascript and css file

```
<style type="text/css">
    .LockOff
    {
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .LockOn
    {
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 105%;
        height: 105%;
        background-color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 20%;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        opacity: 0.80;
    }
</style>


 <script type="text/jscript">
    function skm_LockScreen() {
        var lock = document.getElementById('skm_LockPane');
        if (lock)
            lock.className = 'LockOn';
    }

</script>



  <div id="skm_LockPane" class="LockOff">
    <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image/default.gif" />
    <br />
    Please wait a moment...
</div>
```

This is my css , javascript and Div at last and at last on button click i want to use this function which calls this Javascript function.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGenerateReport" runat="server" Text="Generate Report"OnClick="btnGenerateReport_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:skm_LockScreen()" ToolTip="Click here to generate the report." />
```

My Problem is, if i use this Button without Updatepanel it work fine.
but if i use this button with updatepanel it start to run and get the data but after the postback completed its not stop or hide it continue to run even after getting the data in Gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Use This trigger

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
<ContentTemplate>
   // Your Code
</ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
     <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnGenerateReport" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```